# DIficuldades em editar HTML no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Boa tarde a todos ! Preciso estar traduzindo um texto dessa página(anexada o print do local exato) onde estou tendo dificuldades em editar o arquivo... já tentei por plugin e pelo Poedit e não consegui... tem como acessar a página HTML ? Se tem, como ? Se não tiver, como posso editar isso ? Obrigado pela atenção [image: ![Product Description]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixFll.png)

Answer (score 1):

Você está certo de que colocou os arquivos de linguagem pt_BR (importante a nomenclatura) nos devidos diretórios do tema, ou mesmo no *wp-content/languages/themes/nomedotema-pt_BR*? Caso esteja certo quanto a estes detalhes e mesma assim a tradução não foi identificada, é provável que este termo não esteja declarado no seu arquivo de linguagem.

A maneira mais amigável e imediata de fazer isso é com o plugin Loco Translate. Através do Loco basta você  ir em Loco Translate > Themes > Seu tema > Linguagem desejada > e "Sync" pro plugin identificar as strings que possam estar faltando.

Caso queira alterar através do HTML, basta usar um editor de sua preferência e mandar fazer uma pesquisa em todos os arquivos do seu tema pelo termo que deseja traduzir.

As vezes ocorre de o texto estar adicionado dentro do CSS através de um *content: "texto"*, dê uma inspecionada pra tentar identificar isso também.

Qualquer dúvida, tamo aí!